# Should I be using Django for this?

Tags: python, django, web-applications

It is very possible that the answer to this question is simply “rather use Flask”, but I am hoping I can get a good enough excuse to actually get it working in Django.

**TLDR - Basic overview of the statistical model pre-Django:**

I built a model in R which I am busy porting over to Python. The model is a financial model that analyses past behaviour of client payments in order to estimate future expected losses & repayment. The model performs a number of data imports from an existing SQL database which itself gets populated by the company’s source system. The SQL database is ever growing and contains thousands of tables with loads of financial, historic, client data. The model imports what it needs and then we perform a bit of gymnastics in order to obtain a few bespoke parameters (i.e. we calibrate the model). Once all this is done, we apply the parameters to the latest set of loans in order to estimate the aforementioned forecasts.

**Purpose of the app:**

The main purpose of the web app is to “white box” the model. Clients were complaining that they have no feel for the numbers and would like to see the inner workings. For all intents and purposes, it is a silly request, but the client is paying and I will oblige. So the goal is to build an app that allows the user to execute sub portions of the model and in the end do a full model run themselves.

To this end, I enrolled in a 50+ hour Django course and enjoyed it very much. However, in the end I learnt how to build social blogs from scratch, but nothing close to what I am trying to achieve of course.

**Question:**

Which brings me to the question of whether I should be pursuing this in Django or not.

I have been tempted to write this post for many weeks now, but I am fully aware that this is not a very ‘good’ forum question. These forums usually requires very specific singular questions that are short, discreet and solvable.

**What I have attempted:**

I have managed to build an app with a front-end that allows a user to make a few selections such as “Date”, “Country” etc. which is submitted via a `form` to a `view` which finally kicks off a fairly complex python script (which itself performs SQL imports and Pandas computations) and eventually returns a `DataFrame` which gets presented to the user.

**Rant:**

In this, I don’t see where I need “Django Models” and I don’t know if I even need to use Model Based Forms or Model Based anything for that matter.

I feel like I am missing the entire point of Django which is a tragedy in and of itself.

**One last thing:**

The other thing that I can’t get clarity on is the following: As mentioned, the model uses an **existing** SQL database that sources massive amounts of data and then executes Python scripts which performs various statistical and data mining computations. Is it possible (or even sensible) to create “Django Models” from the existing SQL database, and perhaps the more elementary question (I am very much a noob in Django), why would I want to create “Django Models” of the SQL database? What is the point? I am not persuing a social blog where I want to save posts and comments, I need to click a few buttons which execute python scripts and presents the results to the user.

I hope someone can decipher what I am trying to achieve and help me on the right road.

Thanks

Comment: Regarding the existing SQL database: If I understood correctly you are only reading data from the existing DB. I think you shouldn't use Django Models for existing DB. here is why: (1) one of the main reasons to use Django Models is to manage data (specially update and insert rows) and you just need to read data, (2) managing multi DBs is not easy specially when the insert source is different from Django model,(3) in your case connecting to existing DB with data with Django model is hard, (4) because of security reasons you should keep the existing DB intact & get data from it in a secure way.

Comment: And in your question: Do you have any other way? I mean do you want to know if it's possible in Django? or you need to know how to do it in Django? or you are comparing Django with another solution like Flask?

Comment: I have experience in both Flask and Django and I think developing in Django is way easier from Flask specially if you are noob. In your case if it way me I would use Django and based on the volume of transactions and request ether read data from existing DB or importing and storing selected data from existing DB to my project DB in a scheduled task. And with Forms: in my experience it's depending on type of fields and validations and complexity you can use Model Based Forms or not. In many cases writing custom Django forms or even no Django forms (just plain HTML form) is better.

Comment: @SeyedMohammadHosseini agreed, gut tells me to avoid creating Models from the existing DB. To your question, I don't know what is the best way to build this (I simply researched "web aps" and it came down to RShiny or Django or Flask. RShiny looks like a toy and 9/10 articles imply that Flask is a subset of Django so logically if I am going to learn something new I might as well learn the Rolls Royce if you follow what I mean. Based on your response I am comfortable to continue with Django. I will accept your answer and thanks for the input.

Comment: @SeyedMohammadHosseini I guess what's bugging me is that I am using Django "purely" because it can execute Python scripts in a web app. I am not using any of the many other amazing features of Django and it makes me feel a bit like a savage.

Comment: if I want to compare Django with Flask It's like choosing Prefabricated wall against building a wall from scratch yourself in the process of building a house. If you have time and you have time and experience, creating your wall (using Flask) might be better but otherwise with a well Prefabricated wall (Django) you don't miss any thing. I my opinion Django has provided many tools to make the process of building the web app easier so you don't need to use all of them and with Flask you may need to build lots of these tools.

Comment: To wrap it up: For building a web app I think you should use Django and don't worry to use it as you want. You can implement functions as you can and as you like and it's not an obligation to use all Django tools BUT as an advice always look for better ways to satisfy your needs and don't stuck in a place with your current knowledge and In my experience using and study open source projects (or any project that has been written by some body else) will give you new perspective and improve you.